# Custom UITableViewCell's subviews using auto layout - no xibs, all in code

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, autolayout, heightforrowatindexpath

Custom UITableViewCell's subviews added in code using auto layout works (verified). However the whole point of doing this was to not have to calculate the height of each tableview cell and the delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath expects a height while drawing the tableview.

How can I figure out this height based on content using the auto-layout (visual format language based addition in code already added and working) and return it to this heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Also I'm I can't really do this on a background thread (or can I?) and therefore if I have a UITableView using this backed by a list of say 1000 records, this will take forever, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autolayout in this case just means that you don't need to calculate the frame sizes of your subviews within each cell. It's got nothing to do with the heightForRowAtIndexPath method - this is used by the table view to define the cell's frame, which will then inform the layout of the subviews.

Using Autolayout to determine the heights would likely be pretty slow, and you can't do it on a background thread. If you have 1000 rows then I'd consider a hierarchical structure instead of a single table as that will be pretty tedious to scroll through. You could also consider calculating the heights at the point of setting or creating the data.

You *may* be able to set up an offscreen view using your constraints, populate it with your data for each item, then record and cache the height. However you'd have to do this at the data end rather than in the height method, as it would be far too slow.